# Botching a KSH for loop somehow

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, ksh

This particular script doesn't have any practical value. I'm just trying to get better at KSH scripting as that and bash are what are predominantly used in my work environment.

The goal of the script is to repeat the `if...then` command `5` times. However, when I called the script to run it, it simply doesn't load at all - no output. I have to ^C to end the process. I ran the `if...then` command independently of the `for` loop in a different script and it worked as desired.

I'm still fairly new to scripting, so bear with me here. Also, I will say that I did try this as a `while` loop with the same result.

Please see the code below and let me know if you have any questions. I'm not sure what to do here. Thank you.

```
#! /bin/ksh

currentping=$( ping 8.8.8.8 | sed '/^PING/d;/^$/d;/^-/d;/transmitted/d;/^rtt/d' | awk '{print $7}' | awk '{print substr( $0, length () -3) }' | sed 's/\=//' )

for i in {1..5};
do
if [[ $currentping -lt 100 ]];
then
echo "Your ping is $currentping."
elif [[ $currentping -ge 100 ]];
then
echo "Your current ping, which is $currentping, sucks. Go find better internet!"
else
echo "Your connection sucks!"
fi;
echo $i
done
```

In addition, I ran `ps` and confirmed that the script is running, but no output.

Comment: run it with `ksh -x script.sh` to see where it's hanging

Comment: Note that you set currentping _outside_ the loop. Are you expecting to see something other than the same message output 5 times?

Comment: @glennjackman I actually did try currentping inside the loop. Same result. To your other point, I’m hoping to see 5 unique ping results over the course of a few seconds.  Thank you.

Comment: the `sed` comman(s)d looks incorrect, have you verified that it runs at the command line ?  Most likely it is the first command to set currentping that is hanging.

Comment: @mao Yes, I tested that whole chain of awk/sed commands on the command line. It worked hosted fine.

Comment: @glennjackman - The `ksh -x + sed 's/\=//'
+ ping 8.8.8.8
+ sed '/^PING/d;/^$/d;/^-/d;/transmitted/d;/^rtt/d'
+ awk '{print $7}'
+ awk '{print substr( $0, length () -3) }'`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this looks like a buffering problem

```bash
ping 8.8.8.8 | sed '/^PING/d;/^$/d;/^-/d;/transmitted/d;/^rtt/d'
```

shows the output in real time

```bash
ping 8.8.8.8 | sed '/^PING/d;/^$/d;/^-/d;/transmitted/d;/^rtt/d' | cat
```

appears to "hang"

I tried various placements of `stdbuf -oL` to no avail.

I'd suggest you want this, assuming you have GNU grep:

```bash
currentping=$( ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP 'time=\K\d+' | tail -1 )
```

Comment: Yep, I just came to that conclusion a few moments ago. When I initially started this experiment, I had specified a specific number of packets. I went back into my previous commands and learned that the it was functioning correctly when the ping test wasn't continuous. Thanks!